# Youtube embedded videos Done button not working in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, webview

I am passing an URL link of youtube to a WebView. The video plays in full screen due to which the navigation bar hides, in order to bring the navigation bar back we have to click the "Done" button in the upper left corner. My app works fine with iOS 9 devices but in the latest update i.e iOS 10 this is not working. The done button does not respond or else the screen goes blank and video continues to play. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

This is how i pass the URL